# How to specify the root namespace for a variable when you are in a namespace

Tags: c++

It works when I do:

```
namespace UnitTesting {class UnitTest_1;}

namespace NLa
{
    class Search
    {
       friend class UnitTesting::UnitTest_1;
    }
}
```

But what if `class UnitTest_1` is not in a namespace ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `::` prefix to access the global / unnamed namespace

```
friend class ::UnitTest_1;
```

Your original sample could just as easily be written as

```
friend class ::UnitTesting::UnitTest_1;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to anything in the global namespace using just `::`:

```
class UnitTest_1;

namespace NLa
{
    class SearchSolr
    {
       friend class ::UnitTest_1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
friend class ::UnitTest_1; // Works on namespace-less classes
```

or

```
friend class UnitTest_1; // Works on both namespaced & namespace-less classes
```

Comment: My bad, it only works assuming you are `using` the namespace it is declared in...